# Как OpenSSL добавить в линковку CLion (используется cmake и mingw)

Tags: c++, mingw, cmake, clion

Как добавить OpenSSL в линковку проекта?

Я видел FingOpenSSL (cmake), но не понятно, что с этим сделать.
Прошу дать пример, как добавить OpenSSL в линковку проекта.

Answer (score 1):

[Документацию читали](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindOpenSSL.html)? Все ж элементарно:

```
find_package(OpenSSL)

add_executable(yourapp ...)

target_link_libraries(yourapp ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: читал.
Все равно ошибки. Ошибки: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2d9deb6656ee75e12bd87264e240bd5c
cmake: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/79f72d364ce2e5d3b5384e5ffa683073

Comment: Установить переменную `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` пробовали? Она должна показывать на директорию, которая содержит `lib` и `include` опенссля.

Comment: Можно пример как установить?

Comment: Либо `cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=c:\openssl\`, либо в cmake-gui через окошки и кнопочки.

Comment: Стоит, но инклуд подключить нельзя (пишу #include и нет выбора библиотек из openssl)
DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=${PROGRAMFILES(X86)}\GnuWin32 -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=${PROGRAMFILES(X86)}\GnuWin32\lib -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=${PROGRAMFILES(X86)}\GnuWin32\include\openssl

Comment: Тогда еще `include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})`.